# Implement Synthetic API Request_body on Terraform (Datadog)

Tags: terraform, datadog

I'm trying to develop a Synthetic API test on Terraform for Datadog.
The API in question need a Request_Body parameter to properly make the test.

I've search in many sites on how to implement such Request_body parameter in Terraform but so far, I couldn't see any example of it.

Can someone help me with this?

```
resource "datadog_synthetics_test" "TEST_Status" 
{
type = "api"
subtype = "http"
request_definition {
  method = "POST"
  url = "(...)"
  
}
request_headers = {
  "origin" = "(...)"
  "content-length" = "1340"
  "accept-language" = "en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8"
  (............)
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You missed `body`, it's mandatory for `post` requests

```
    request_definition {
      method = "POST"
      url = "(...)"
      body = "body content ..."      
    }
```